# ImportError No module named pyaudio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, audio-recording, importerror, pyaudio

I am writing a program in Python on RaspberryPi, But I am getting an error

```
ImportError No module named pyaudio
```

After that I tried

```
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
```

but again get another

```
fatal: destination path 'pyaudio' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Can you please guide me that how do I install PyAudio in RaspberryPi

Comment: Have you read: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=25173 ?

Comment: @JonClements As ur advice I followed , but again get another error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Remove the directory PyAudio which already presen in /home/pi and then try these steps**

```
sudo apt-get install git

sudo git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git

sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev

sudo apt-get install python-dev

cd pyaudio

sudo python setup.py install
```

or also you can try this

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

let us know if u need more assistance or any other trouble

Answer (score 11):

If

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

did’t work try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply install PyAudio by executing this command:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 6):

`python -m pip install pyaudio`

This command works if you already have `pip` installed.
If not, first install `pip` and `ty`

Answer (score 2):

> download suitable version of PyAudio File: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Then Open CMD
type : C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts add "pip install"

file location where you download the PyAudio whl file add File name

example:**C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl**

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Mac and installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh), then

```
brew install portaudio 
pip install pyaudio
```

solved my issue

Comment: Works for me. Thanks. Mac (intel 2019)

Answer (score 0):

Install using below command

`conda install -c anaconda pyaudio`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyaudio
```

this worked for me,hope it helps you too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30289466)

Comment: At least two existing answers already suggest this. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```