# No mdule name 'pyaudio'

Tags: python, pyaudio

My error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\gaura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 108, in get_pyaudio
>       import pyaudio ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/gaura/PycharmProjects/jarvis_prog/jarvis.py", line 46, in
>   
>       takeCommand()   File "C:/Users/gaura/PycharmProjects/jarvis_prog/jarvis.py", line 28, in
>   takeCommand
>       with sr.Microphone() as source:   File "C:\Users\gaura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 79, in **init**
>       self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()   File "C:\Users\gaura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py",
>   line 110, in get_pyaudio
>       raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation") AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: It says right there `install pyaudio`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError No module named pyaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140972/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio)

Answer (score 1):

- Go to this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

- Check your python version & download the pyaudio file which supports your version i.e. if your are using python 3.9, you will have to download
  **PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl** Note: This file is for 64-bit os
- Open the terminal in the folder where the file is downloaded and enter the following command to install the file. Replace the `some-package.whl` with the name of the downloaded file

> pip install some-package.whl

- Install the SpeechRecognition module using `pip install SpeechRecognition` and then run the program

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deal with speech recognition there is a module named **SpeechRecognition** 
install it by

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system lacks `pyaudio`.

You can simply grab the Wheel package from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and then install it with `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`. Then try to install your package.