# Installing the pyaudio module on Windows with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I am trying to install the pyaudio module..I have tried several methods that were discussed previously on stackoverflow and other platforms related to pyaudio but nothing that were discussed were working correctly..I have installed all the required packages required to install pyaudio but nothing seems to be working.. I have the latest version of pip and i am using python 3.7 version...Here is what i am getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this info? Please include more details, where is the installation failing? what error messages are you getting?

Comment: I now have edited the question with the Error included please

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140972/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio) answer your question?

Comment: No it didn't...i have tried everything answered there but nothing seems to be working..Also it is asked 5 Years ago that might be the reason

Comment: Try `pip install PyAudio` with the caps

Comment: Same problem...Still same error

Comment: What OS are you running

Comment: 64 bit operating system

Comment: That isn't an operating system, I mean Mac, Windows, Linux

Comment: Yeah as i mentioned in the question i am using Windows 10

Comment: Lol where? could you quote it?

Comment: Sir i mentioned it in the title of the question please

Comment: I answered your question, read below

Comment: Ok thanks can you please tell me how to decide which one suits the best for my system?

Comment: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: OK Thank You so much...I have tried it previously as well but it was not working but i'm try it again

Comment: Did it work? If so, please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1):

PyAudio hasn't been officially updated on PyPl yet to work with Python 3.7

First download the `.whl` file for *your system* from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio). Then run pip again with this command:

`pip install "path/to/your/.whl/file"`

Comment: @JoeAnn I'm not sure if you were trying this answer but I just changed it

Answer (score 0):

You can install pyaudio externally through website.
Website :  [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Search for PyAudio and download it