# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' in Google Colab

Tags: python, import, pip, pyaudio, modulenotfounderror

I imported 'pyaudio' library in Google Colab, but ModuleNotFoundError occurs.
However, it worked just a week ago... :( But does not Now..

I tried to re-install pyaudio in colab with the next codes but same errors occur.

```
!sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
!pip install pyaudio
```

How can I do?

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-627d880c2452> in <module>()
      4 from pydub.effects import normalize
      5 
----> 6 import pyaudio
      7 import scipy.signal
      8 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140972/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio

Comment: # Please Refer Here This Link Might Possibly Answer Your Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140972/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio

Comment: ### This Link Might Possibly Solve Your Prop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140972/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio

Comment: Use some other library like librosa.  pip install librosa